# Совет в структуризации таблицы mysql

Tags: php, mysql

есть задача внедрить следующую функцию:

В админке есть страница пользователя где администратор видит различную информацию об пользователе и может с ней взаимодействовать и манипулировать.

На этой странице нужно сделать поле в котором администратор сможет оставлять комментарий к пользователю.
Вопрос в реализации, лучше сделать отдельную таблицу примерно такого содержания:

```
id user_id comment
```

И при рендере страницы обращаться к ней и запрашивать комментарий по id пользователя с таблицы в которой хранятся комментарии.

Или же просто в таблице пользователей добавить поле comment и уже в него записывать текстовую информацию?

Заранее благодарю за помощь, справедливости ради могу сказать что в комментариях может быть как и пусто так и находиться обширное количество текста или текст с тегами.

Comment: Если пользователей менее 10 млн то второй вариант с дополнительной колонкой. Если более и надо часто выполнять сложные групповые функции с таблицей, то первый вариант может оказаться предпочтительнее

Answer (score 0):

Добавляйте дополнительную колонку. Этот вариант намного проще.

Answer (score 0):

Банальное правило разделения логики разных сущностей, советует вам, естественно организовать дополнительную таблицу с отношением `один ко многим`.

Сорри за вопрос на вопрос, но как вы оставите 10 комментариев в одну колонку в таблице к пользователю?)
P.S. Костыли типа огромного джейсона - ну не вариант.